# Program design button focus issue

Tags: java, user-interface, focus, jbutton

**I have a program that has a row of buttons. Those buttons are enabled or disabled depending on the component that currently has focus.**

At least they should be. I don't know how to do it. Not properly at least. Here are my ideas:

1. Each component whoose focus determines if a button is enabled would enable/disable it on focus gained/lost event. Catch? It would also disable the button if I tried to click on it (since it would also loose focus). I can *maybe* work around it, but it complicates things a lot.
2. Create a global listener that listens for focus lost and focus gaind events and then disables and enables the buttons respectively.

It seems that the method no2 is way to go since it's way more centralized, but is there maybe another way that would be better?

EDIT:
This is what I ended up doing:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener()
        {
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getID() == 1004) //FOCUS_GAINED
                {
                    if (Main.getGui().getActiveDocument() != null)
                    {
                        close.setEnabled(true);
                        save.setEnabled(true);
                        send.setEnabled(true);      

                        if (e.getSource() instanceof Element)
                        {
                            addChapter.setEnabled(true);
                            delete.setEnabled(true);
                            superscript.setEnabled(true);
                            subscript.setEnabled(true);

                            if (e.getSource() instanceof Title)
                            {                   
                                if (((Title) e.getSource()).getChapter().getType() == 0)
                                {
                                    addQuestion.setEnabled(true);
                                    addListElement.setEnabled(false);
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    addListElement.setEnabled(true);
                                    addQuestion.setEnabled(false);
                                }

                                addAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                            }

                            else if (e.getSource() instanceof Question)
                            {
                                addQuestion.setEnabled(true);

                                if (((Question) e.getSource()).getAnswerCount() < 5)
                                {
                                    addAnswer.setEnabled(true);
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    addAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                                }

                                addListElement.setEnabled(false);
                            }

                            else if (e.getSource() instanceof Answer)
                            {
                                addQuestion.setEnabled(true);

                                if (((Answer) e.getSource()).getQuestion().getAnswerCount() < 5)
                                {
                                    addAnswer.setEnabled(true);
                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    addAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                                }

                                addListElement.setEnabled(false);
                            }

                            else if (e.getSource() instanceof ListElement)
                            {
                                addListElement.setEnabled(true);

                                addQuestion.setEnabled(false);
                                addAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                            }
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            addChapter.setEnabled(false);
                            addQuestion.setEnabled(false);
                            addAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                            addListElement.setEnabled(false);
                            delete.setEnabled(false);
                            superscript.setEnabled(false);
                            subscript.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        close.setEnabled(false);
                        save.setEnabled(false);
                        send.setEnabled(false);
                        addChapter.setEnabled(false);
                        addQuestion.setEnabled(false);
                        addAnswer.setEnabled(false);
                        addListElement.setEnabled(false);
                        delete.setEnabled(false);
                        superscript.setEnabled(false);
                        subscript.setEnabled(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, AWTEvent.FOCUS_EVENT_MASK);
```

Comment: Try changing the button states only on `focusGained` event.  If required, add a Swing `Timer` with a short delay in the `focusLost` method that would allow for a short time between the `focusLost` event and the actual time you disable the buttons...

Comment: That could help, but if user presses the button but decides to keep it pressed without releasing it, it would get disabled without triggering. I could make the action event fire on button press maybe, but that would confuse the user...

Comment: What happens if you call `setFocusable(false)` on each `JButton`?  That way, it shouldn't take the focus from the component that has it, so your problem with option (1) won't apply.

Comment: But then how do you click one (of the buttons)?

Comment: You're kidding?  Swing doesn't let you click buttons that aren't focusable?  That sucks!  If that is the case, I withdraw my suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you said "disable" :P

Comment: OHMYGOD. I love you @DavidWallace. And Mr. MadProgrammer. I love you both. Very much. A lot. Really. :D